# can I use the codename one camera kit library to take a picture automatically from the code?

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to using codename one and I can not understand how we can take a picture from the camera using captureImage (); from the camerakit library.
I know it's possible with the Capture API (Capture.capturePhoto ();) but this library uses an application to take the photo and I want to do this directly

I created a button :

```
        FloatingActionButton capture_button = 
                     FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CAMERA);
        capture_button.bindFabToContainer(hi, CENTER, BOTTOM);
        capture_button.addActionListener(e -> {

            ck.captureImage(); 
                             .............
```

and after that I tried to get my picture from the onImage function but it does not work.

```
@Override
public void onImage(CameraEvent ev) {

    try {

        byte[] jpegData = ev.getJpeg();
        String str = new String(jpegData);
            InputStream stream = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(jpegData);
        OutputStream out = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("MyImage.jpg");
        Util.copy(stream, out);
        Util.cleanup(stream);
        Util.cleanup(out);

        StorageImage out = StorageImage.create("MyImage.jpg", jpegData, -1, -1);
            ............................
        }
```

the byte array is empty. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Camera Kit broke a bit after its release due to changes in Camera Kit which is still not 1.0 level. This is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2596). [Camera kit](https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android/) was supposed to reach 1.0 status months ago but still hasn't reached that point. We 
are waiting for it to be at 1.0 level so we can make fixes against a stable version.

We also need a bit of time/resources to do that work which is something we are sorely lacking.